# Getting thread 1: signal sigabrt when trying to use tap gesture recognizer to open url

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to use a tap gesture recognizer to open an URL when tapping an image.
The code builds successfully but when I try to tap the image, it terminates and displays

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

in console. Console also displays

> [Hello.ViewController clickToOpen]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

And there is a

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

in the line

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" in AppDelegate.swift.

The ViewController code is below:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Hello
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var helloName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageToTap: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    nameTextField.delegate = self

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("clickToOpen")))
    self.imageToTap.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    self.imageToTap.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true 
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    helloName.text = "Hello \(textField.text!)"
    textField.text = ""
}

//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func clearButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    helloName.text = "Hello"
}
@IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
@IBAction func clickToOpen(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/") {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your tap gesture code & From swift 3.x you need to use `#selector`

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(clickToOpen))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```